# Unlocking TAB key for multiple users in protected sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I want to create a protected sheet and allow multiple users to edit specific ranges. The problem is when I do that the TAB key stops working. I tried to insert macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.TransitionNavigKeys = True
UserInterfaceOnly = True
End Sub
```

And TAB works... sort of. It's not moving to another unlocked cell for this user, but moves entire view by jumping to last column on screen.
Is there any solution for this or should I look for workaround and protect ranges in some other way?

Comment: Are you sure there are unlocked cells on the sheet?

Comment: The problem is, unlocking cells allows everyone to edit them and I don't want that. I want to only unlock cells for specific user.